# Conditional expectation on moving average errors

Tags: mathematical-statistics, error, moving-average

I'm currently solving a problem 2.2.29 (a) of textbook ***Mathematical Statistics: Basic Ideas And Selected Topics: 1 (Bickel, Doksum) 2nd edition, Volume I, p.147***.

> Let $e_i = (\epsilon_i + \epsilon_{i+1})/2, i = 1,\ldots,n$ where $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_{i+1}$ are i.i.d. with mean zero and
> variance $\sigma^2$. The $e_i$ are called *moving average errors*.
>
> Consider the model $Y_i = \mu + e_i, i = 1,\ldots,n$.
>
> Show that $E(Y_{i+1} | Y_1,\ldots,Y_i)=\frac{1}{2}(\mu + Y_i)$. That is, in this model the optimal MSPE predictor of the future $Y_{i+1}$ given the past $Y_1,\ldots,Y_i$ is $\frac{1}{2}(\mu + Y_i)$.

I was wondering whether the left hand side of the equation, which is

$$E(Y_{i+1}|Y_1,Y_2,\ldots Y_i)\quad\quad\quad\quad (1)$$

is partially wrong. Instead, I think it should be

$$E(Y_{i+1}|Y_i)\quad\quad\quad\quad (2)$$

---

With a little bit of calculation, the given equation

$$E(Y_{i+1}|Y_1,Y_2,\ldots Y_i) = \frac{1}{2}(\mu+Y_i)$$

can be simplified into a equivalent form

$$E(e_{i+1}|e_1,e_2,\ldots e_i)=\frac{1}{2}e_i \quad\quad\quad\quad (3)$$

But every attempt to derive the above equation (3) has failed.

Instead, I think I found a counterexample to (3).

Suppose that n=3 and $$\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3,\epsilon_4\overset{i.i.d}{\sim}N(0,\sigma^2)$$

Then,

$$\begin{bmatrix}{e_1} \\ {e_2} \\ {e_3}\end{bmatrix} \sim N\left( \begin{bmatrix}{0} \\ {0} \\ {0}\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} && {\frac{\sigma^2}{4}} && {0} \\ {\frac{\sigma^2}{4}} && {\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} && {\frac{\sigma^2}{4}} \\ {0} && {\frac{\sigma^2}{4}} && {\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

> ***Theorem***
> $$\begin{bmatrix}{X_1} \\ {X_2}\end{bmatrix} \sim N\left( \begin{bmatrix}{\mu_1} \\ {\mu_2} \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}{\Sigma_{11}} && {\Sigma_{12}} \\ {\Sigma_{21}} && {\Sigma_{22}} \end{bmatrix}\right)$$ Then, $$X_{2|X_1=x_1}\sim N(\mu_2+\Sigma_{21}\Sigma_{11}^{-1}(x_1-\mu_1),\Sigma_{22}-\Sigma_{21}\Sigma_{11}^{-1}\Sigma_{12})$$

By the above theorem,

$$E(e_3|e_1,e_2)=-\frac{1}{3}e_1+\frac{2}{3}e_2$$

But if we put i=3 in equation (3), the result should be

$$E(e_3|e_1,e_2)=\frac{1}{2}e_2$$

Am I missing something? Is my counterexample correct?

If I'm wrong, could you please give any hint or reference that I can study to solve the problem?

Comment: I think the textbook is wrong.  This is a MA(1) time series model and it is well known that the best one-step ahead prediction depends on the entire observed history of the process (unlike the case for an AR(1) model where the best prediction only depend on $Y_i$).  You can also see this from the fact that while $\Sigma_{11}$ is a sparse (tridiagonal) matrix, $\Sigma_{11}^{-1}$ is not.

Comment: Hi: Besides what Jarle said, are you certain that $e_i$ is defined like that because it is a function of $\epsilon_{i+1}$ which is in the future ? So, defining $e_i$ like that really doesn't make sense.

Comment: @mlofton I just double-checked the text book and $e_i$ is a  function of $\epsilon_{i+1}$. I don't think that  $\epsilon_{i+1}$ means anything future. We can formulate the problem with  $\epsilon_{i}$. I think the series is just MA(1) as Jarle said.
If you still think that $\epsilon_{i+1}$ is wrong, then how should the problem be fixed? Does your suggestion resolve my issue, especially the counterexample I gave?

Comment: Hi sepiabrown: I think the timing really matters because the conditional depends on the subsrcipting so, whether you know the future or not, really changes the problem. I would find out whether there are typos because, the question is confusing enough without having to deal with possible typos. Maybe email the author of the text ?